# finding orthonormal basis using gram schmidt

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

symmetry matrix $\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 1 & 1 \\
      1 & 0 & 1 \\
      1 & 1 & 0  \end{array}\right) $
one of  eigen value is $\lambda_1=2$ and one of eigen vector is $x_1=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} \frac{1}{\sqrt3} \\
       \frac{1}{\sqrt3}  \\
       \frac{1}{\sqrt3}  \end{array}\right) $
then i found the two other eigen value is $\lambda_2=-1 $ & $\lambda_3=-1$
but the question want eigen vector that is orthogonal to each other and has magnitude $
|x_2|=|x_3|=1$

when i tried to compute it using gram schmidt, when $v_2=x_2-\langle x_2,x_1\rangle x_1$
here  produce $0$? but all the vector seem already linear independent to each other?

```
  three of vector that i choose are
```

$x_1=\begin{eqnarray*} \begin{bmatrix}   \frac{1}{\sqrt3}\\   \frac{1}{\sqrt3} \\    \frac{1}{\sqrt3} \\ \end{bmatrix},x_2= \begin{bmatrix}    -1 \\    1  \\    0  \\ \end{bmatrix} \text{ for } \lambda=-1,x_3= \begin{bmatrix}    -1\\    0 \\    1  \\ \end{bmatrix}\text{ for } \lambda=-1, \end{eqnarray*}$

i choose$\begin{eqnarray*} x_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\begin {bmatrix}    1\\    1 \\    1  \\ \end{bmatrix}, x_2= \begin {bmatrix}    -1  \\    1  \\    0 \\ \end{bmatrix}\end{eqnarray*}$
and using gram schmidt,$ \begin{eqnarray*}\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\begin {bmatrix}    1\\    1 \\    1  \\ \end{bmatrix}. \begin {bmatrix}    -1  \\    1  \\    0 \\ \end{bmatrix}\end{eqnarray*}$ it gave zero 
whats wrong??
and there seem many combination that i can choose as my eigen vector for $\lambda=-1$, what is the rule for that?

Comment: $x_1$ belongs to a different eigenspace than the other two vectors, so you already know that it’s going to be orthogonal to them. There’s no particular good reason to include it in the orthogonalization process. You just need to find an orthonormal pair that spans the eigenspace of $-1$.

Comment: @amd to get orthonormal pair for $-1$ is it means i have to apply gram schmidt twice to $x_2$ and $x_3$ right?

Comment: That’s right, although you really only need to normalize $x_2$.

Comment: Also, since you’re working in $\mathbb R^3$, you could cheat and take the cross product of $x_1/\|x_1\|$ and $x_2/\|x_2\|$ for the third eigenvector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong. It happens that your vectors $x_1$ and $x_2$ are already orthogonal. So, if you apply Gram-Schmidt to $\{x_1,x_2\}$, then, since $\|x_1\|=1$, what you get is $\left\{x_1,\frac{x_2}{\|x_2\|}\right\}$. Actually, what you have to do is to apply Gram-Schmidt to $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ but, since $x_1$ is already orthogonal to the other two, just apply Gram-Shmidt to $\{x_2,x_3\}$ and then add $x_1$ to what you got.

Comment: thankyou, but here did you mean i should apply gram schmidt to $x_2 $ & $x_3$?

Comment: @Vixf Indeed, that's what I meant. Since they are linearly independent, there«s no problem with that.

Comment: thankyou so much!! after some calculation, i got $x_1=\begin{eqnarray*} \begin{bmatrix}   \frac{1}{\sqrt3}\\   \frac{1}{\sqrt3} \\    \frac{1}{\sqrt3} \\ \end{bmatrix},x_2= \begin{bmatrix}    0 \\   \frac{-1}{\sqrt2} \\     \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \\ \end{bmatrix},x_3= \begin{bmatrix}    \frac{-2}{\sqrt6}\\    \frac{1}{\sqrt6}\\    \frac{1}{\sqrt6}  \\ \end{bmatrix}, \end{eqnarray*}$ but is this same as if i change $x_3$ to$x_3=\begin{eqnarray*}  \begin{bmatrix}    \frac{-1}{\sqrt6}\\    \frac{-1}{\sqrt6}\\    \frac{2}{\sqrt6}  \\ \end{bmatrix}\end{eqnarray*}$ ?

Comment: and also after i applied gram schmidt to $x_2$ & $x_3$, i need to applied it again to find the $x_3$ since it is still not orthogonal to the other vector right?

Comment: @Vixf I don't understand any of your questions. The vectors$$x_1=\begin{bmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt3}\\\frac1{\sqrt3}\\\frac1{\sqrt3}\end{bmatrix}\,\ x_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\\frac{-1}{\sqrt2}\\\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix},\text{ and }x_3=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{-2}{\sqrt6}\\\frac1{\sqrt6}\\\frac1{\sqrt6}\end{bmatrix}$$are already an answer to your problem, although I don't understand how you got them (they're not what you would get applying Gram-Schmidt to the original vectors). Why would you want to change $x_3$?

Comment: here i applied gram schmidt to $x_2$ & $x_3$ and got $\begin{eqnarray*} \begin{bmatrix}    0 \\   \frac{-1}{\sqrt2} \\     \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \\ \end{bmatrix} \end{eqnarray*}$ and already orthogonal to $x_1$ but still need one more vector for $x_3$, and i applied gram schmidt once again to $x_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\\frac{-1}{\sqrt2}\\\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}$  and $\begin{eqnarray*} \begin {bmatrix}    -1  \\    1  \\    0 \\ \end{bmatrix}\end{eqnarray*}$. yes i counted it wrong for $x_3$ but now i got the right one

Comment: @Vixf What you write makes no sense. If you apply Gram-Schmidt to two linearly independent vectors, what you get are two vectors, not just one. And in this specific case, the vectors that you should have obtained are$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{-1}{\sqrt2}\\\frac1{\sqrt2}\\0\end{bmatrix}\text{ and }\begin{bmatrix}\frac{-1}{\sqrt6}\\\frac{-1}{\sqrt6}\\\frac2{\sqrt6}\end{bmatrix},$$which are orthogonal to $x_1$, as they should.

Comment: you got that two vector by applying gram schmidt twice right? first i applied it to $\begin{eqnarray*} \begin {bmatrix}    -1  \\    1  \\    0 \\ \end{bmatrix}\end{eqnarray*}$ and  $\begin{eqnarray*} \begin {bmatrix}    -1  \\    0  \\    1 \\ \end{bmatrix}\end{eqnarray*}$ and got $\begin{eqnarray*} \begin{bmatrix}    0 \\   \frac{-1}{\sqrt2} \\     \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \\ \end{bmatrix} \end{eqnarray*}$ but here i only obtained one vector that orthogonal and need one more,

Comment: so  i applied again gram schmid to $x_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\\frac{-1}{\sqrt2}\\\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{eqnarray*} \begin {bmatrix}    -1  \\    1  \\    0 \\ \end{bmatrix}\end{eqnarray*}$ and got $\begin{bmatrix}\frac{-1}{\sqrt6}\\\frac{-1}{\sqrt6}\\\frac2{\sqrt6}\end{bmatrix}$